# neo4j Apoc subgraphAll filter on child, and skip others

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

```
MATCH (n{key: 'KEY001'})
CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(n, {
     maxLevel:8,
     relationshipFilter: 'HAS_E>'
     })
YIELD nodes, relationships     
RETURN nodes, relationships
```

It returns like this

```
        (E) # Here is KEY001
        /\
    (E)    (E KEY_SKIP .. skip this and its child)
    /\      \
  (E) (E)   (E)
```

Expected:
I want to have sub graph filter at middle nodes, keeping parents nodes for example at KEY004

```
        (E) # Here is KEY001 .. keep this
        /
    (E) # KEY_004, want to filter here. 
    /\  
  (E) (E)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `blacklistNodes`:

```
MATCH (n{key: 'KEY001'})
MATCH (unwanted{key: 'KEY003'})
CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(n, {
     maxLevel:8,
     relationshipFilter: 'HAS_E>',
     blacklistNodes: unwanted
     })
YIELD nodes, relationships     
RETURN nodes, relationships
```

For sample data:

```
MERGE (a:E{key: 'KEY001'})
MERGE (b:E{key: 'KEY002'})
MERGE (c:E{key: 'KEY003'})
MERGE (d:E{key: 'KEY004'})
MERGE (e:E{key: 'KEY005'})
MERGE (f:E{key: 'KEY006'})

MERGE (a)-[:HAS_E]-(b)
MERGE (a)-[:HAS_E]-(c) 
MERGE (b)-[:HAS_E]-(d) 
MERGE (b)-[:HAS_E]-(e)
MERGE (c)-[:HAS_E]-(f)
```

It returns the expected results:

```
╒═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╤═══════════════╕
│"nodes"                                                              │"relationships"│
╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╪═══════════════╡
│[{"key":"KEY001"},{"key":"KEY002"},{"key":"KEY004"},{"key":"KEY005"}]│[{},{},{}]     │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴───────────────┘
```

To 'white-list' filter children of the root, you can use for example:

```
MATCH (n{key: 'KEY001'})-[:HAS_E]->(m)
WHERE NOT m.key='KEY002'
WITH n, collect(m) as unwanted
CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(n, {
     maxLevel:8,
     relationshipFilter: 'HAS_E>',
     blacklistNodes: unwanted
     })
YIELD nodes, relationships     
RETURN nodes, relationships
```